# Android - SQLite Comparing system date to date in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date, comparison

The basic idea of what I want to achieve is to make a comparison between the current Android system date and an existing date in a SQlite database.

The idea is to 1.) If the database does not contain contain a entry with today's date, then allow new entry

2.) If the database already contains an entry from today's date, then revoke entry and output error message.

My DBAdapter currently has a method that does the following:

```
public Cursor getDate(String date) {
String where = KEY_DATE + "=" + date;
Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                where, null, null, null, null, null);
if (c !=null) {
    c.moveToFirst();
}
return c;
}
```

and the method i'm using to make the comparison is:

```
public void addRecord (View view){
    db.open();
    Cursor cursor = db.getDate(dateString);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Date"); 
        builder.setMessage("Entry for today exists, would you like to update this instead?"); builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
        db.close();
    }
    else{

Do other work..
```

both Date's used for comparison is formatted using this code:

```
long longDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateString = sdf.format(longDate);
```

where I'm simply calling 'dateString'

My trouble is that it doesn't perform the correct checks and skips my else statement completely even tho i know there is an existing 'date' in the database. Is my SQL statement correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up the query like this:

```
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, KEY_DATE + "=?", new String[] {date}, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use dates on my database, But I save them as a long value with the getDate() function.
Also I have found problems depending on the type of Date variable you use.
I like java.util.Date and never ever use the sql date variable.
I do where conditions for my data and all comparison are by getTime() which is a Long value.
With the long value you get from the database just do new Date( longValue ) and that way you get the correct date variable.